# getting ddev and drush site install to work for multisite install

Tags: drush, ddev

I am trying to create a new drupal 7 multisite from my ddev web container. While drush si runs fine, creating another db and site fails.
I run ddev ssh from the host and then issue a

```
drush site-install --sites-subdir=mysite --db-url=mysql://db:db@db/mysite --db-su=root --db-su-pw=root
```

This doesn't seem to work.
While just entering the mysql-db as root with `mysql -uroot -h db`

and creating the new database works.

Running drush with --debug option shows, that the user db can not access the DB:

```
sql-query: DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS test8; CREATE DATABASE test8 /*!40100 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 */; GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON test8.* TO 'db'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'db'; FLUSH PRIVILEGES; [4.26 sec, 2.03 MB]               [notice]  
Executing: mysql --defaults-extra-file=/tmp/drush_lGzF0v --database=information_schema --host=db --silent  < /tmp/drush_GTSajV  
ERROR 1044 (42000) at line 1: Access denied for user 'db'@'%' to database 'test8'  
Failed to create database: ERROR 1044 (42000) at line 1: Access denied for user &#039;db&#039;@&#039;%&#039; to database &#039;test8&#039; [4.3 sec, 2.03 MB]
```

**Workaround**
add the Grant like said in the comment below:

```
grant all on *.* to 'db'@'%';
```

**and if I now run the same drush command twice in a row it works and installs the site.**

I haven't tried this on a different stack, so maybe it is a bug in drush site-install.
I did the same for drupal 8 on ddev too and it shows similar behavior, even if it produces different errors. The same workaround, running the command twice fixes the site install.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is a drush bug? I note that if I grant the 'db' user privs `grant all on *.* to 'db'@'%';` then it all works with `drush site-install --sites-subdir=mysite --db-url=mysql://db:db@db/mysite` - Is that good enough for you? You could actually add the grant into your post-start hooks...

Comment: Also, could you please edit the title to mention --sites-subdir, since that's the real issue here? `drush si` works fine out of the box.

Comment: The grant didn't fix the problem here. Changed the titel to multisite install. Will check on a different environement to confirm if it is a drush bug.

Comment: I was definitely able to run the command I gave after doing the grant. But the good news is this is definitely a solvable problem. Can you say a little about why you need to use multisite? I've always considered it a pretty bad idea on Drupal, based on old-style servers where you were trying to save disk space. (I never knew that drush had a --sites-subdir in all these years!)

Comment: You are right. You need the grant even if it doesn't show up in the grants table later. But we do need to run the command twice somehow. 
We have a rather large multisite installation running right now and I just wanted to check our install skript for new multisites. With D8, docker and k8s in Prod we will move away from multisite in the future.

Comment: So were you successful after doing the grant?  Are you successful with this now? I have no idea why you'd need to do it twice.

Comment: Just ran into this while working on https://www.drupal.org/project/operations/issues/3389217. I tried adding a print_r($databases); to the multisite setting.php file. That file isn't even accessed when using drush si unless you use @rafy's method declaring the subdir and db-url. This is definitely a drush issue independent of DDEV. Greg Anderson gave the same explanation in https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/190051/need-steps-to-install-multisite-configuration-using-only-drush-i-e-multi-site-i